# How to plot the following function graphs?

Tags: plot, axis

So, I would like to be able to plot a function (it doesn't have to be these functions, per se) in the style as the ones that follow:

Also, I how do I put the descontinuity "dot" - sorry for the poor Mathematical terms, as I am not English -, and how can I draw a dashed line (as the one below, sort of greyed out) to represent (not in this case, mind you) an assymptote?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Function Graphs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an ad hoc way to produce such plots: just add nodes at the discontinuities.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt},
    declare function={%
    f1(\x)=1-1*pow(\x-0.6,2);
    f2(\x)=1.5-0.25*\x*\x+0.03*pow(\x,4);
    f3(\x)=0.6-0.05*x*x+0.2*pow(\x-1,3)+0.06*pow(\x-1,4);
    }]
\pgfplotsset{axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},xmin=-2.5,xmax=4,ymin=-1,ymax=3,
    }
\begin{groupplot}[every axis plot/.append style={smooth},
    group style={group size=2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=1cm},height=5cm,width=6cm]   
\nextgroupplot
  \draw[dashed] (1,{f2(1)}) -- (1,0);
  \addplot[domain=-1:1] {f1(x)} coordinate[pos=1,circ,fill=white];
  \addplot[domain=1:3] {f2(x)} coordinate[pos=0,circ,fill=black];
\nextgroupplot
  \addplot[domain=-2:2.5] {2.5*f3(x)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]